# Login with Bcrypt(4);

Tags: php, mysql, blowfish

I'm trying to create a secure login system to my website, here's what I've got.. And the errors I receive.

```
<?php

try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=****", "****", "****");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE LOWER(`username`) = :username";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':username', strtolower($_POST['username']));
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
require ('includes/blowfish.class.php');
//$bcrypt = crypt(md5(md5("P5IAO".$_POST['password']."AR19W")));
$bcrypt = new Bcrypt(4);
if ($bcrypt->verify($_POST['password'], $row['password'])) {
    echo "Logged in!";
}
} else {
echo 'User NOT found.';
}
?>
```

I get this error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'bcrypt not supported in this installation. See http://php.net/crypt'`

Comment: The error message is as straightforward as it gets

Comment: Well, thanks for the input. When I follow it's instruction it leads me to the crypt API, I'm very new to using this sort of secure method and would appreciate a direction over letting me know how much of a beginner I am.

Comment: I've fixed this, seemed I needed to update my PHP to 5.3 with my webhosting provider.